# Specific display view to avoid broken screen part

Tags: nvidia, screen, display-resolution, xrandr

Recently I broke my screen at bottom left, so I need it fixed to top right and a bit smaller, maybe using `xrandr` or something.

[image: black rectangle with green rectangle top right]

The green rectangle is the screen I need (with width x1 ; height y1)

The black rectangle is the whole screen (with width x; height y)

The red area is the broken part.

How can I get the display to occupy only the green area?

Answer (score 4):

You may use NVidia underscan setup. For example, I have `1280x800` monitor and I want top-right side with size of `900x700`.

1. `gksu nvidia-settings`
2. X server display configuration tab → Select your monitor
3. Set `(x-x1)/2=(1280-900)/2=190` value for underscan which gives me `900x562`, just fine. Apply, by default it will cut from all sides.
4. Click Advanced, I find:

   ```
   ViewPortIn:  900x562
   ViewPortOut: 900x562+190+118
   Panning:     900x562
   ```

   Change `ViewPortOut` to right and up to leave space only at left and bottom

   ```
   ViewPortIn:  900x562
   ViewPortOut: 900x562+380+0
   Panning:     900x562
   ```

   Apply
5. Some driver/adapter combination have weird behavior, like mine.

   I got `900x562` on top-right corner OK, left & bottom are black OK, mouse can only move inside that `900x562` box OK, but desktop didn't change its size correctly, it is cut from right and bottom edges FAIL.

   I use `1px` panning trick to correct it. Even if the desktop scrolling by `1px` horizontally or vertically, it is an acceptable solution.

   Change by +1px: `Panning: 901x562` or `Panning: 900x563`.

Done, Here is what you should get:

[image: nvidia underscan to avoid damaged portion of the monitor]